# My 5 month old cat suckles on me while I sleep

Tags: cats

I have a half siamese black cat and she loves to suckle on anything that I wear (thankfully not on my skin). I don't usually mind it as she's super hyper and it's one of the few times she's calm. She'll usually come and join me on the sofa and suckle for a little before going to sleep, which is fine. But lately I've been waking up at 6 or 7 in the morning to the kitty laying on me and suckling on my sleeve, with her claws in my arm. Unfortunately I live in a studio apartment so just shutting her out of the bedroom at night isn't an option. Is there anyway I can kindly discourage her from doing this? Usually there's no way to distract her from suckling, no toys or food will work, she's really focused on it which I why I gave in and let her suckle my tops as she didn't do it all that often and the fabric wasn't going to break off, so no harm done. But the amount of suckling has only increased ans I don't think it's wise to continue letting her suckle me when I sleep.

Comment: Hi Cara! Welcome to pets.se. Please check out the questions I have provided they will surely answer yours :)  Feel free to come to our pets chat if you would like to discuss some of the answers! https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box